# Thumbnail in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I created a thumbnail with ng-repeat directive.When i click the add button,cards will be created automatically.What i want to do is to pass add button automatically right side after every thumbnail is added.In my code, there is an add button(it is fixed) and it creates thumbnails.Here is my code

```
      `<div  ng-show="list">
         <div class="row-sm-3 row-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail"
                style="width: 270px; height: auto; display: inline-block; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid #5bc0de"
                ng-repeat="location in list track by $index">
                  <div class="name"><strong>Name :</strong> {{location.name}}</div><br>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  `

 `<div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="width:180px; height:200px; margin-top:7px;
        border-radius:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#ffffff;border-color:#46b8da"
            ui-sref="context.location"><span style="font-size:18px; color:#337ab7">Add</span>

        </button> 
 </div> `
```

Comment: would be great if you can create a minimal verifiable example of the issue. People might be able to help you better.

Comment: Like this: https://hizliresim.com/POrb2O

Comment: No you can use Jsfiddle.net or here built in snippets at Stackoverflow to create a working demo.